# tmux monitor-activity -- active activity vs stopped activity

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I'm curious if it is possible to have a different visual indicator for active activity (e.g. stream of text) and stopped activity (e.g. command executed, printed a few lines and stopped) in an inactive window.

iTerm2 will display the tab title in purple when something is actively happening in an inactive tab and red text when something has previously happened but there is currently happening in an inactive tab. I find this behavior really useful and I'd like to have something similar in tmux if possible.